# Не сразу срабатывает редирект через window.location.href

Tags: javascript, redirect, fetch

Есть такой код, он отправляет данные на сохранение в бд:

```
async function click_add() {

        const response = await fetch("api/products/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                productName: document.getElementById("productName").value,
                productCategory: document.getElementById("productCategory").value
            })
        });
        if (response.ok === true) {
            console.log('added successfully')
            alert("Successfully added!");
            window.location.href = '/';
        } 
    }
```

И вот этот `console.log` и всё остальное срабатывают только во второй раз, но данные в бд отправляются и сохраняются и в первый раз, и во второй. В чём может быть проблема?
Могу предполагать, что проблема вне метода, поэтому оставлю полный файл тут:

```
(async function(){
    let elem = document.getElementById("button_add");
    elem.addEventListener("click", click_add);
    let elemBack = document.getElementById("back-to-list");
    elemBack.addEventListener("click", redirecting);
    async function redirecting() {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
    async function click_add() {

        const response = await fetch("api/products/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                productName: document.getElementById("productName").value,
                productCategory: document.getElementById("productCategory").value
            })
        });
        if (response.ok === true) {
            console.log('added successfully')
            alert("Successfully added!");
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: ну если срабатывает только во второй раз, значит в первый условие if не равно true........ соответственно надо смотреть что приходит (или что там на серваке отсылается как и когда)

Comment: Вы точно с сервера JSON ответ делаете и заголовки все выставили как надо при ответе?

Comment: Ну видимо да, сервер точно JSON возвращает

Comment: Иначе бы оно вообще не работало, я думаю

Comment: Оно не срабатывает только первый раз после запуска программы. Если ее запустить, и потом несколько раз вызывать этот метод - оно работает сразу

Comment: "*вообще не работало, я думаю*" --- то есть вы любите гадать, а не проверять?

Comment: Я проверила только что) Интересный факт - если поставить режим Fast 3G или Slow 3G - проблема пропадает. А если режим No throttling - то не срабатывает первый раз.

Comment: "*Я проверила только что*" --- каким образом? что инструмент разработчика во вкладке Network в качестве response показывает в первый раз а что во второй? (когда это плохо работает)......

Comment: Network отдаёт 200, если Fast 3G и ошибки нет, а если No throttling - я вообще не вижу, что происходит. Во второй раз  - 200

Comment: я не про статус, а про данные, которые присылает сервер...... и я не про Fast 3g, а про ту скорость, на которой именно проблемы.